# Any way on starting an agent without the attach libary?

Tags: java, agent, javaagents

How can I have a Java Agent start without the attach library?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) which implements the important bits for Windows and Linux.

Attaching an agent can be done with:

`` jattach PID load instrument false /path/to/agent.jar` ``

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Java agent when starting a program using the `-javaagent:./agent.jar=arg` command. The `./agent.jar` is the location of the jar file containing the agent code. It is required to add a manifest containing an entry `Agent-Premain` naming a class containing a `premain` method.

For a running agent, the tools.jar is required. As an exception, I implemented the attachment protocol [for Unix systems for HotSpot in Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.6.1/net/bytebuddy/agent/ByteBuddyAgent.AttachmentProvider.ForUnixHotSpotVm.html).